# How can I attach Amazon Network Interface To Subdirectory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a two websites in my amazon EC2 instance.

One is `domain.com/` and the other is in a subfolder `domain.com/secondsite`

What I need is to create an addon domain pointing to the subfolder.

So, I tried creating a new amazon network interface and attaching an elastic IP to it. But I'm not sure if this is the right way.

If it is than how can I connect my network interface to the subdir, and if it is not correct, than how can I achieve what I want?

Comment: There is no need to get interfaces involved, this is configured on webserver software (probably apache). If you provide details about current config, it should be fairly easy to setup.

Comment: So, if I point the domain to the Ip address of the server, the other addon domains can be redirected through Apache only ? I'm asking this because there are so many ways like I recently discovered Route53 and I'm not sure which one is the best practice.

Comment: Just point the new domain to the same IP address (whatevere the DNS service provider is, rote53 or any other, it does not matter). Then, handle the redirrection on webserver. It is a common thing to run many websites/domains on one ip address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code in the apache file

```
    # Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses 
    NameVirtualHost *:80 

    <VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot /www/example1 ServerName domain1.com 
    # Other directives here 
    </VirtualHost> 

    <VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot /www/example1/wordpress_site2 ServerName domain2.com 
    # Other directives here 
    </VirtualHost>
```